# Android: how to set width/height of YoutubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout, youtube

I am using the [YoutubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) in my app. I create the fragment from code (not xml) and inject it in the activity using the FragmentManager:

```
String video_id = "LHcP4MWABGY";

YoutubeFragment youtubeFragment = YoutubeFragment.newInstance(video_id);

mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main, youtubeFragment).commit()
```

How can i define the width/height of the youtube fragment? I've tried with:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams)youtubeFragment.getView().getLayoutParams();

params.height = 400;

youtubeFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

but this gives me a NullPointerException. The exception is on this line:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams)youtubeFragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
```

This is the error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
                at com.test.revy.radioshake.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:249)
                at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:346)
                at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1550)
                at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3830)
                at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5855)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Post your logs. Also point to the line where the exception occurs.

Comment: I've added the log

Comment: I think after adding the fragment you didn't wait for it to complete the transaction, i.e. `youtubeFragment`'s `onCreateView()` has not yet been called or has not been completed. Either way view is not set.

Comment: So wait for a callback that the transaction has indeed been completed, or move your resize code in `YoutubeFragment`.

Comment: And if I remember correctly then you'll have to set `LayoutParams` to parent from `getView()` like so `getView().getParent()` which will return the container of your `YoutubeFragment`.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that the .commit() call of the FragmentManager is an async call (thought it was synchronous). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Abbas suggested, the problem is Transaction().[..].commit() of the FragmentManager (async call).
Solved using commitNow() instead of commit():

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main, youtubeFragment).commitNow()
```

Comment: You should instead call resize in `onCreateView()` of `YoutubeFragment`.